# How to exclude certain portions of my website from bots/web crawlers?

Tags: indexing, bots, web-crawler, search-engine

I have made custom segments/blocks around my website which I use it for advertising/marketing. Google search bots are considering those as part of my website and gets confused of what my site really is versus advertisement.

This negatively impacts my SEO. Is there a way I can register or use certain directives or elements to inform google and other bots to avoid crawling that portion or even if crawled should not be considered as part of that page.

I am aware of robots.txt file but that is for an entire page. I would like to block a certain blocks within each page. This could be a side bar a floating bar.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In this case the question has already been asked and answered there: [Preventing robots from crawling specific part of a page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16390/preventing-robots-from-crawling-specific-part-of-a-page)

Answer (score 1):

there's no way to ensure all bots don't index parts of a page.  it's kind of a all or nothing thing.

can could use a [robots.txt](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/intro) file and with

```
Disallow: /iframes/
```

then load the content you don't want indexed into iframes.

there's also the [data-nosnippet-attr](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/robots-meta-tag#data-nosnippet-attr) tag attribute.

Comment: that would block the entire page. I would still need the crawler to read my page but not a particular block.

Comment: updated answer.